# Is it ok to upload hair pictures and videos only?

Tags: awrah, hair

I make hair related content, where i share haircare/ growth tips for which i have to show my hair only so that audience can rely on my techniques and sometimes i have to show tutorials for certain hairstyles.
But i dont show my face, so is it still haram? Because as long as I know hair itself is not a sexual part, and i am not showing my face , so nobody can have a slightest image of who i am.
Because i am thinking to expand it as my hair brand but i am very confused that should I continue or not

Answer (score 1):

NO it is haram. The (awrah) of a female is all of her body except her face and hands up to the wrist. So it is not allowed to show or post other parts online. This parts is what Allah ordered to hide, so our job is to obey Allah and not make our own classifications for whether it is sexual or not. Prophet Muhammad says what means: you will never leave something for the sake of Allah, but Allah will give you something better instead of it, so you should stop doing that. You can find alternative ways to advertise for your work.